# How to get the Cordovo navigator object instead of the javascript navigator object?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm very much new to cordova. I'm trying to create a simple app, where the user is able to take a photo, and that photo is then displayed in an html image tag.

I have ran into a few issues, which I'm finding difficult to solve:

(1) firstly when   running this demo mobile app on android,

```
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onSucess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
```

navigator.camera is retuning null. This is because the browser is referring the navigator object to the javascript navigator object instead of the cordova one. How can I fix this?

(2)   When Running on the android emulator in Visual Studio, I'm getting the following error when trying to assign to the  with the imageUri

code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {};


    $("#takePhotobtn").click(function () {
        //  camera plugin code to open camera and display pic.
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSucess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
    });

    function onSucess(ImageData) {
        $("#candidatePhoto").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + ImageData);
        alert("yes this works updated");
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

error: Failed to load resource: data:image/jpeg;base64,blob:http%3A//localhost%3A4400/c78426c3-2f0e-4b9a-955c-df0005519358 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: Hey, Make sure navigator.camera is used after device ready.  navigator is available after the deviceready event.

Comment: I tried that, see above code, no luck

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody also stumbled into this problem, I fix this by adding the reference to cordova.js in my main index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>Audit Chamber</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```